# JavaFX GridPane layout issue

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a simple login form. See its prototype below:

[image]

I decided to use GridPane as a layout container and cannot align LOGO by centre and span submit button.

That is my login.fxml:

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<GridPane alignment="CENTER" hgap="20" vgap="10">

  <ImageView fitHeight="82.0" fitWidth="296.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2">
    <Image url="logo.png"/>
  </ImageView>

  <Label text="login:" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>
  <Label text="password:" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>

  <TextField prefWidth="200" prefHeight="20" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>
  <TextField prefWidth="200" prefHeight="20"  GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>

  <Button text="submit" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.fillWidth="true" />

</GridPane>
```

And that is what I get:

[image]

Comment: GridPane alignment determines the alignment of the entire GridPane contents as a whole.  For an individual child, add `GridPane.halignment="CENTER"` to that child.

Comment: @VGR ohh, thanks. And what about button?

Comment: You’ll need to override the button’s maximum width.  Try `maxWidth="Infinity"`.

Comment: @VGR yeah. It worked out. Thank you a lot.